# Visual Studio keyboard short-cut to complete default accessors {get; set;}

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, accessor

I am looking for a keyboard short-cut to complete creating the default accessors for a property in a C# class.

Something like...
I start typing:

```
public int Id
```

Then I press one or more keys, and I endup with:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The shortcut is the trigger "prop":

> `prop`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>`int`<kbd>tab</kbd>`Id`<kbd>tab</kbd>

and you end up with:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: It is also possible to get the old VS2005 version of the shortcut so that you can have the full getter and setters displayed instead of the short version.

Comment: it actually feels slower

Comment: I have to hit tab twice to initially move the cursor from `int` to `Id`

Answer (score 16):

Try with `propfull` , then TAB Twice and you'll get:

```
private int myVar;

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myVar;}
        set { myVar = value;}
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also create a custom snippet:

```
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>GetSet</Title>
            <Description>Inserts getter/setter shorthand code</Description>
            <Shortcut>gs</Shortcut>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="CSharp">
                <![CDATA[{ get; set; }$end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: Here's how to actually add a `Code Snippet`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Comment: And this should be the accepted answer. Now `gs [tab]` does the whole `{ get; set; }`

Comment: Found your answer while looking for [my own older, identical snippet answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8236311/957950) while setting up a new environment. Note that this only generates the `{ get; set; }` and doesn't include a field for the property name, as the other answers do.
...Would've appreciated a citation or pingback; I supposed it's possible you chose completely identical wording independently though.

Comment: Sorry, I usually do the citation, I think I encountered the same problem in the very same days of this question and your answer was the solution. Sorry though and +1 to your comment and your other answer. Thanks for reminding me. @brichins

Comment: No worries - thanks for the acknowledgement. I normally wouldn't care (although I always need some rep to get additional SO privileges), but I've been dealing with some attribution issues at work this week and it rubbed me the wrong way at the end of a long day. I'm glad this approach was useful to you (and hopefully others), that's what really matters.

Answer (score 4):

The shortcut is using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. Press these keys after writing:

int loginID;

Then you will get the following encapsulation:

```
    int loginID;

    public int LoginID
    {
        get { return loginID; }
        set { loginID = value; }
    }
```