# C# shortcut or shorthand getter setter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, shortcut

Is there a short way to create the getter and setter in c#?

```
public string fname {get; set;}
```

Is there short hand to generate `{get; set;}`?

Comment: lol. Is that not short enough?

Comment: You never would have made it in the stone age before auto-implemented properties.

Comment: Lol maybe Microsoft can do a better job an come up with {g;s;}

Comment: I still remember the paleolithic age where you had to write your own fname_get() and fname_set(string) methods.

Comment: As long as people are making fun of the question I'll throw something into the ring as well. Type {get; set;} once and the copy it and then paste it where you need. CTRL+C / CTRL+V is pretty fast and short.

Comment: Creating alot of properties and getting tired of typing { get; set; } over and over. Yes a I am a slow typer. And a bad typer to. Although in the time i went searching for this i could have just typed them out. LOL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio keyboard short-cut to complete default accessors {get; set;}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936550/visual-studio-keyboard-short-cut-to-complete-default-accessors-get-set)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

yea type **prop** and press TAB. Visual Studio has a snippet for automatic property.

For property with public get and private set, you can use **propg** and press TAB.

For complete non auto property you can use **propfull** and press TAB.

Comment: Thanks. I was doing the prop tab tab like all the other websites say, but they never say 1st tab will take you to the type, 2nd tab to the name.

Comment: And`Shift Tab` will allow you to cycle back.

Answer (score 19):

If you *just* want the getter and setter, as orignally asked for, you could also create a custom snippet:

```
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>GetSet</Title>
            <Description>Inserts getter/setter shorthand code</Description>
            <Shortcut>gs</Shortcut>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="CSharp">
                <![CDATA[{ get; set; }$end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Save the above as a .snippet in your snippets folder. Typing 'gs' and pressing Tab will insert `{ get; set;}` and move to the end of the line.

---

### Edit

In VS Code, this would be a custom [user snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets) in your `csharp.json` file:

```
"Getter Setter": {
    "prefix": "gs",
    "body": [
        "\\{ get; set; \\}",
        "$1"
    ],
    "description": "Insert shorthand autoproperties"
}
```

Either of these examples could easily be modified/duplicated to also do `{ get; }` (use a `readonly` backing field) or `{ get; private set; }`

Comment: To import the snippet into Visual Studio, just copy the xml from above, paste into Notepad, and save it somewhere on your computer as get_set.snippet. Then in VS, choose Tools > Code Snippet Manager > Import and browse to the file. After that you can just type gs and press Tab to insert the get and set block.

Answer (score 16):

The shortcut is the trigger "prop":

```
prop<tab><tab>int<tab>Id<tab>
```

and you end up with:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: I guess this has changed with newer versions or my settings are different.  My key combination is the following;  prop<tab>int<tab><tab>Id<tab>

Answer (score 3):

When I type prop & TAB I get:

```
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

Is there a way to set it up so it's all on one line so it looks like:

public int MyProperty { get; set;}

**UPDATE!!!**  I figured it out.

Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> C# --> Code Style --> Formatting --> Wrapping -->  Put a checkmark in the "Leave block on a single line" option.  It even uses the "get; set;" as an example.
[image: Setting Get;Set; to one line.]

Comment: I just found this in MonoDevelop. It's under Preferences -> Source Code -> C# source code -> C# Format: Edit -> Category: Braces -> Property declaration -> Allow automatic property in one line (Force one line)