# Is there a way of generating getter, setter functions in visual studio 2012 like in eclipse

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I had looked up solutions here [C# shortcut or shorthand getter setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015445/c-sharp-shortcut-or-shorthand-getter-setter) but when I implement one of solutions

visual studio generates code like

```
private int myVar;

public int MyProperty
{
    get { return myVar; }
    set { myVar = value; }
}
```

what I want vs auto getter setter generator is to create getter setter for all of my variables and depending using their name like

```
private int id;

public int Id
{
    get { return id; }
    set { id= value; }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: For new properties you just need to type `prop` and then hit Tab

Comment: There may not be a solution with VS2012 out-of-the-box.  But, Resharper does it: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Properties.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Just create a field then `Refactor->Encapuslate Field`. Shortcut is <kbd>ctrl + R, E</kbd>

Comment: is it possible to do this for all variables at once

Comment: Not possible, it just does one variable at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Type propfull tab tab

Then double-click on the variable "myVar" and replace it with what you want.  VS will then replace the all other instances of it.  You can also double-click on the type to change that and VS will change the auto code accordingly.

You can then edit the property name